# Xcode Use PDF Image in Bar Button Item Size Too Big

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have a PDF file in my image assets file in my Xcode project. I'm trying to create a bar button item that uses that PDF image. But whenever I set the image property in Interface Builder to the image it takes over most of my tab bar and removes the title.

I have a left bar button item with the system item stop. So it looks like an `X` icon. I would like to do the same thing on the right side with my settings PDF image I have.

Is there a way to fix this sizing issue within Interface Builder? If not how can I fix this in code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using Code what I do when the image size is too big, I resize the `UIImage` before rendering/setting on the `UIControl`. I have this extension on `UIImage` that helps re-scale an image.

```
// MARK: - Used to scale UIImages
extension UIImage {
    func scaleTo(_ newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage ?? self
    }
}
```

Using this would look like this

```
let defaultImage = UIImage(named: "someimagenamehere")?
    .scaleTo(CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    image: defaultImage,
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(self.someselectorhere(_:)))
```

**UPDATE**: This is what it would look like using @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    @IBInspectable
    var scaledHeight: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.image = self.image?.scaleTo(CGSize(width: self.scaledHeight, height: self.scaledWidth))
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var scaledWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.image = self.image?.scaleTo(CGSize(width: self.scaledHeight, height: self.scaledWidth))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this within the storyboard itself?

Comment: My guess would be to create a `IBDesignable` `UIBarButtonItem` Subclass which has a some `IBInspectable` properties that would help re-scale the images.

Comment: Using `IBDesignable` worked perfectly. Thanks so much. Will award bounty at the end.

Comment: @CharlieFish can you add the IBDesignable UIBarButtonItem subclass you made as an answer please

Comment: @sbru hi kindly look at my answer again, this is what it would roughly look like, but be warned, I haven't tested this code yet.

Comment: Thanks @ZonilyJame!

Comment: how to use CustomBarButtonItem in storyboard?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

Comment: @Mikael well the best way to solve that, is to modify the `scaleTo` method return an optional `UIImage`. I'm not adept in the inner workings of the `UIGraphicsXX` functions myself.

Comment: I fixed it by adding a guard on the optional and returning self when it's nil. When the execution occurs, it tries to scale with a width or height with 0 as value and that seems to produce a nil for UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().

Comment: great solution...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is a good approach. However, in my case, I had one item pdf and the rest where png. I faced also the issue of working on a started project and all the icons were different sizes.

I ended up doing:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {

    convenience init(image: UIImage?, size: CGSize, tintColor: UIColor, target: Any?, action: Selector?) {
        let holderView = UIButton()

        let button: UIButton = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        holderView.addSubview(button)

        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true

        button.setImage(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.tintColor = tintColor

        if let target = target, let action = action {
            button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        self.init(customView: holderView)
    }

}
```

I hope it helps